# Using linear interpolation to predict value in matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-interpolation

I have a set of data and would like to use linear interpolation in Matlab to find the corresponding value of a specific point.

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
y = [1 2 3 4 5 4 2 6 8];
xq = [1:0.25:9];
vq1 = interp1(x,y,xq);
plot(x,y,'o',xq,vq1,':.');
```

After doing this, is there any way for me to find the value of x given a value of y? For example, when y = 3.5, x = ?

Answer (score 2):

**Simple Interpolation**

You could just interpolate the other way...

```
% Your code
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
y = [1 2 3 4 5 4 2 6 8];
xq = [1:0.25:9];
yq = interp1(x, y, xq);

% Interpolate your newly interpolated xq and yq to find x = x1 when y = 3.5
x1 = interp1(yq, xq, 3.5)
```

**Finding Zeros**

This approach is more complicated but, depending on your data, may be more applicable.

You could use some sort of root finding approach using [`fzero`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html), and a function defined as below

```
% Initialise
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]; y = [1 2 3 4 5 4 2 6 8];
% Define function, like your interpolation, which will have a zero at x=x0
% when y = y0. 
y0 = 3.5;
yq = @(xq) interp1(x, y, xq) - y0
% find the zero, intial guess must be good enough
y0 = fzero(yq, 1)
```

As noted in the comments, the intial guess must be "good enough" - this is not only for convergence within `fzero` but if, during the evaluation, a value of x is tested which is outside of your interpolation then it will break.

Example:

```
y0 = fzero(yq, 1)
% >> Exiting fzero: aborting search for an interval containing a sign change
%    because NaN or Inf function value encountered during search.
%    (Function value at 0.971716 is NaN.)

y0 = fzero(yq, 5)
% >> y0 = 3.5, as expected from the input data.
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, Since you want to use Linear Interpolation model in order to know interpolated value all you need is 2 samples around it.

For example, if you wonder when you get the value `y = 3.5` all you need to find 2 adjacent points with one having value lower than `3.5` and the other value higher than `3.5`.

Then all needed is to use [Line Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation) to infer the exact value of `x` at the point.

What I'm trying to say is if you only interested to find the `x` for a certain `y` value, there is no need to interpolate all data.